# issue in pushing CSV data to mongodb using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, csv

I'm very new to mongodb and nodejs. Here's a task I'm finding difficult to execute, I want to parse a .CSV file through nodejs and push the data into Mongodb. I read the csv data through nodejs using **fast-csv** library but I'm facing difficulty in pushing it into mongodb.

I tried the following code.

```
 var fs= require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/insertDB';
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;


var data;
var readData=fs.createReadStream('x.csv').pipe(csv()).on('data',function(data){
    console.log(data);
})
.on('end',function(data){
    console.log('Read finished');
})


  MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Connection established to', url);
      var collection = db.collection('airports');
      collection.insert(data);
  }
  });
```

My console is printing the data. My error in the console reads as **cannot read property _id of undefined** I tried altering the above code placing the database connection within the else part and I got this error **cannot assign to read only property '_id' of** field names in csv file can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var fs= require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/insertDB';
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;


var data;

MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Connection established to', url);
      var collection = db.collection('airports');
      readData=fs.createReadStream('x.csv').pipe(csv())
                   .on('data',function(data){
                      collection.insert({'data': data});
                   })
                   .on('end',function(data){
                      console.log('Read finished');
                   })

    }
  }); //End of Mongo connect
```

Comment: Hi Amarnadh & BlackMamba,

Thanks guys it worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

`data` in the readstream is the `data` from the callback `function(data)`. `data` later in insert is the `var data` which is null

Comment: Hey Tuan,
Thanks for pointing out, but if we remove var data; it shows data is not defined in the database connection part. is there a way to globally call data in function(data)